# How to retrieve node with an input search with Sigmajs and Neo4j ?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, sigma.js

I am trying to retrieve a node with an inputsearch field but it doesn't work. I think there is a mistake in the cypher query. Does somebody can help me?

```
var inputsearch= document.getElementById('inputsearch').value;
var buttonSearch=document.getElementById('buttonsearch');    
buttonSearch.addEventListener('click', drawGraph(inputsearch));   




function drawGraph(inputsearch){


    sigma.neo4j.cypher(
      {
        url: 'http://localhost:7474', user: 'neo4j', password: 'neo4j' },

      'match (n)-[r]->(m) where n.data.node.label =~ ".*(?i)'+inputsearch+'.*" return r,m,n;',s
      ,function(s) {
        console.log('Number of nodes :'+ s.graph.nodes().length);
        console.log('Number of edges :'+ s.graph.edges().length);
        for(var i =0;i < s.graph.nodes().length; i++){
          node = s.graph.nodes()[i];
            s.settings('touchEnabled', true);
            s.settings('mouseEnabled', true);


}})};
```

Comment: what are you trying to search with this cypher query ?

Comment: I am trying to search all Nodes who get in their labels my query String. For example: I write matrix and i get all nodes with matrix label, and after I can double click on node to expand it

Comment: `label` from sigmajs is not the same thing than a `label` on Neo4j. in your example you are searching a node with the label `Movie` and a property `title` with the value `Matrix`. For a `Person` node the attribut will not be same (it's `name`)

Comment: Ok i understand but it was an example i would like to retrieve a node whatever the label Category (Person, Movie) . Can i do that? Because i have a lot of node labels and i would like to have only one search input to retrieve a node

Comment: I have tried this code, it works well but the node desapear immediately.  
function drawGraph(inputsearch){
  
    
    sigma.neo4j.cypher(neo4jConfig,
    'match (n:Ressource)-[r]->(m) where n.nom =~ "(?i).*' + inputsearch + '.*" return n LIMIT 1;',
    s,
    applyStyle)
    
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a sigma question, but a Neo4j question.

If you want to do this, you should :

- Add the label `Node` on every node
- Add a property `_search` on every node where you should concatenate in **lower case** all the fields you want to index
- Create an index on the property `_search` for nodes `Node` : `CREATE INDEX ON :Node(_search)`

With that your query becomes :

```
MATCH (n:Node)-[r]->(m) WHERE n._search CONTAINS $inputsearch RETURN n LIMIT 1
```

I have update my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sim51/qkc0g58o/69/

Comment: Thank you so much @logisima It was very helpfull for me !!